# Why bother with HTML5 header, main, section elements, et al?

Tags: html

all of this are only for make it more easy to read the html code?  because they dont have any function more than that right ? ;( we can do all without that

```
<Div>

<p>
 Example
</p>

</div>

<p>
  same Example
</p>
```

Comment: Put it another way; we can all live without cars, but it's far easier to use the car than to not use the car. Yes it's possible to code HTML without using version 5, but really.... if there is any perceived benefit in this at all; it's short term, and near-sighted.

Answer (score 3):

> all of this are only for make it more easy to read the html code? because they dont have any function more than that right ?

Not exactly.

These things make it easier for the *browser* and the *website crawlers*, *screen readers*, *page printers*, *meta recorders*, etc., -*basically, any no-human/digital entity*- to read the structure of the page, (combined with [Schema](https://schema.org/) metadata this can be quite powerful).

This means that you can put what you like in the `<nav>` tag or the `<aside>` HTML5 tag because the browser can read the syntax structure and know these are navigation links (therefoe useful for screen readers or for mobile devices to handle correctly) rather than core contents of the page central to the issue discussed on the page (such as details about why HTML5 is a good thing).

A good full answer to your question can be found here:

## [Why bother with Semantics](https://www.kirstencassidy.com/why-bother-with-html-semantics/).

*Summary points from the link above:*

> - More consistant cross browser implementation
> - Style normalization
> - Semantic markup makes glaring differences less likely.
> - Less typing
> - Craftsmanship: When something is well built it is less likely to break.
> - Accessibility
> - Maintainability: Code that makes sense is more maintainable.

*Please bare in mind this article above was written in 2014 so it's references to "some browsers not being up to dat is now moot and old hat.*

Your original statement including `<div>` tags is incorrect as ths is not HTML5 specific and a `<div>` is simply a container element that is used by your webpage styling and application level code such as `javascript` and `CSS`. A div can be anything you want it to be.

Comment: so is for make the browser read better the syntax?

Comment: Not just the browser but *everything* that is not a human. As well as semantic improvements for human code readers, editors, workers.

Comment: so when do u know if u should use header article div etc if all have the same end

Answer (score 0):

it supposes that it helps search engines to give a rank at the webpage and it could be used also for SEO.

https://www.codesmite.com/article/is-there-any-seo-value-in-html5-semantic-elements

Take from the above link:

> Even in 2017 there are very few published case studies or official acknowledgements by Google that having an semantically HTML5 correct website will move you up in the rankings, or create better exposure from public searches. But it is safe to acknowledge that the more semantical detail you provide to bots then the better search engines will be able to understand and index your content. Using HTML5 elements surely can’t hurt.

https://www.inboundnow.com/html5-semantic-elements-mean-seo/

Comment: o that so help to seo if u use the correct semantics

Comment: `it supposes that it helps search engines to give a rank at the webpage and it could be used also for SEO.` This is the same thing.